# Finding this strange bug? It crashes without noticing anything

Tags: c++, crash, buffer

I wrote a function within my code that should create some sort of matrices. It is fine when the size is small, but when it gets bigger, it crashes at the middle of this function without giving any information. I did that with both debug and release mode and same thing happened. Any idea on what can be wrong? Someone suggested me it could be buffer overrun.

In this function when `kl.mechelms` get bigger than a certain number, it crashes. The following code uses a function and gets a 3 by 3 matrix and stores it in `kl.scoff` which size is `[3][3][kl.mechelms][kl.mechelms]`. The problem happens when `kl.mechelms` are like bigger than 7000, but we need far more than that for our code.

Could the function `Calc_3D` which I use within this part cause the problem? I think it shouldn't since it just reads some values.

```
for (int z = 0;z<3;z++) {
    for (int q = 0;q<3;q++) {
        kl.scofsarr[z][q] = new double *[kl.mechelms];
    }
}

for (int i = 0;i<kl.mechelms;i++) {
    cout << "element " << i << "of " << kl.mechelms << endl;
    kl.comments << "element " << i << "of " << kl.mechelms << endl;
    for (int z = 0;z<3;z++) {
        for (int q = 0;q<3;q++) {
            kl.scofsarr[z][q][i] = new double[kl.mechelms];
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0;j<kl.mechelms;j++) {

        Calc_3D(i,j, kl.elmx[j], kl.elmy[j], kl.elmz[j], kl.anglemat[j], kl.dip[j], kl.elmx[i],kl.elmy[i],kl.elmz[i],
                kl.elma[i],kl.rectza,kl.anglemat[i],kl.dip[i], kl.G, kl.v, kl.scofs, kl.rdepth);


        for (int z = 0;z<3;z++) {
            for (int q = 0;q<3;q++) {
                kl.scofsarr[z][q][i][j] = kl.scofs[z][q];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion but you would be better off using `std::vector<double>` instead of managing memory yourself with `new` and `delete`.

Comment: Could you show us the class definition, that we can see the type of the members ?  And the signature of Calc_3D ?

Comment: A 3x3x7000x7000 matrix of doubles requires about 3.5GB of memory.

Comment: 1-Thanks! Well, my advisor told me not to use vector since they slow down the code.
2-Thanks! double **scofsarr[3][3] , and the function is like this:
Calc_3D(int elm1, int elm2, double xobs, double yobs, double zobs, double ostrike, double odip, double xc, double yc, double zc, 
      double clength, double cheight, double cstrike, double cdip, double G, double nu,double scofs[3][3], double rdepth) {
}
3- Thanks! I am running a PC that has 32 GB ram, where about 22 GB is available.

Comment: Get a better advisor.